# Azure App Functions: How to inject a singleton service in a class that is not the function/Component?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-functions

**Azure App Functions 3.0**

I am attempting to log activities and errors from an internal class used by functions but the logs are not correct written, since I cannot instantiate/find the service binded to the correct "ILogger" (the one naturally injected in constructors and functions).

I do not want to pass down the Logger instance through classes from the entry point, **but inject it correctly**.

Tried **new LoggerFactory()** with no success.

```
var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("InfoLogger");
logger.LogInformation("Please, log this information!");
```

Tried **ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance()** with Ninject registering the service provider associated with the logger at startup with no success.

```
        // Startup.cs
        NinjectKernel._kernel
            .Bind<IServiceProvider>()
            .ToMethod(context => builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider())
            .InSingletonScope();

       // MyInternalClass.cs
       var serviceProvider = NinjectKernel.Get<IServiceProvider>();
       var logger = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<ILogger>(serviceProvider);

       logger.LogInformation($"Information Ticket: {ticket} | Data: ...");
```

Any help are welcome!

Comment: Please share the code you tried.

Comment: Please share the code how you configured the methods ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(), Logger Factory(),  injected the dependencies.

Comment: Edited to add the code @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT

Comment: Edited to add the code @Shyju